# Show that $\bigcup_{m \in \Bbb{Z}} \bigcap_{n \in \Bbb{N}} [m-\frac1n, m+\frac1n] = \Bbb{Z}.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Show that $\bigcup_{m \in \Bbb{Z}} \bigcap_{n \in \Bbb{N}} [m-\frac1n, m+\frac1n] = \Bbb{Z}.$

If I first take $x \in \bigcap_{n \in \Bbb{N}} [m-\frac1n, m+\frac1n]$ I have that $$m-\frac1n \le x \le m+\frac1n, \forall n.$$ Now this means that $|x-m| \le \frac1n$ so the infinite intersection would imply that $x-m$ would have to be in every interval of the form $$|x-m| \le 1 \\\vdots \\ |x-m|\le 0$$ but this is eventually $0$ or $\emptyset$?

Comment: it is eventually $\lvert x-m\rvert=0$; i.e., $x=m$

Answer (score 2):

If $m\in\Bbb Z$, then there is one and only one number which belongs to every interval $\left[m-\frac1n,m+\frac1n\right]$, which is $m$. So,$$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\left[m-\frac1n,m+\frac1n\right]=\{m\}$$and therefore$$\bigcup_{m\in\Bbb Z}\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\left[m-\frac1n,m+\frac1n\right]=\bigcup_{m\in\Bbb Z}\{m\}=\Bbb Z.$$